# How to detect location of text in natural scene using OpenCV Python?

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, opencv, python

I'm trying to do a racing bib recognition system. So far I have reduced the region of interest into the torso area where the racing bib is usually located. This is the output that I currently have: 
[image showing the result image after applying preprocessing techniques and canny edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbv8N.jpg)

I am only interested in the racing bib number. I know I have to use stroke width transform but currently I'm stuck at the localization of the racing bib part.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a Convolutional Neural Network that can localise and recognise numbers in an image. This kind of CNN is very easy to make and there are tons of examples in the internet on how to do do it using the MNIST dataset.

For example: http://petr-marek.com/blog/2017/07/31/sequence-digits-recognition-localization/